# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'QueryDict' and 'float'

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm getting the following error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'QueryDict' and 'float'
```

the value passed in 'amount' is 4.90 so I'm confused to why it cannot /.

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    amount = forms.FloatField()
    credits = forms.FloatField()

 def __init__(self, amount, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['amount'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields['amount'].initial = amount
    total_credits = credit_total(amount)

    self.fields['credits'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields['credits'].initial = total_credits
```

I have tried to use float() but this did not work.

cal function

```
def credit_total(amount):

    credit_total = amount / 0.049
    return credit_total
```

I have to note that on my first load of the form it works...

```
 cost_amount = float(request.POST['amount'])
        form = OrderForm(amount=cost_amount)
```

however, on post when I populate the form again it does not....

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
```

however account is now in the POST request.

Maybe I need to do something like so....

```
  def __init__(self, amount=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if amount is none then make amount from args = ammount????
```

Comment: I don't see `/` anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Why a vote to close? Please tell me how I can import this question? I have included everything I have and explained what I have done already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you populate the form from `request.POST`, you are passing the entire `request.POST` as `amount`, which is the first argument to your form's `__init__`. You want to pass it as `data`. You still have to pass something to `amount`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    amount = float(request.POST.get('amount', 0))
    OrderForm(amount=amount, data=request.POST)
```

I think it would be better for you to calculate initial data outside of the form:

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    amount = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    credits = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

...

form = OrderForm(initial={'amount': amount, 'credits': credit_total(amount)})

...

if request.method == 'POST':
     form = OrderForm(data=request.POST)
```

How are you getting amount from `request.POST` when method is not POST? I wish you'd posted your entire view.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `def __init__(self, amount, *args, **kwargs):`. This is not written in many places, but you cannot add your own arguments by name to the list of arguments to the form's `__init__` method.

Don't worry though, all is not lost. What you want is this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    amount = kwargs.pop('amount', None)
    super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['amount'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields['amount'].initial = amount
    total_credits = credit_total(amount)

    self.fields['credits'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields['credits'].initial = total_credits
```

The only thing is, you will need to be careful when instantiating your form. You will need to provide the amount as a named arg, which I see you are already doing.

The reason is that when you are calling `form = OrderForm(request.POST)` you are assigning the POST QueryDict to the `amount` arg.